# Count on one custom dimension and group by another with BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm totally new to BigQuery, please excuse me for any obvious mistake. I'm trying to build a query where I can count the number of distinct element from one custom dimension and group this by another custom dimension.

I tried this but It doesn't work :

```
SELECT
  MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=7,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) AS Author,
  COUNT(MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=10,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL))) AS Articles
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([blablabla-blabla-115411:104672022.ga_sessions_test], TIMESTAMP('20160927'), TIMESTAMP('20161024'))) AS t0
GROUP BY
MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=7,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) AS Author,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"), does this query work? For each entry in `hits`, it selects the `value` for an `index` of 7 as the author, and then counts the number of entries where `index` is 10 as the number of articles. It makes the assumption that there is at most one entry with an `index` of 7 in `customDimensions`.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
   WHERE index = 7) AS Author,
  SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
       WHERE index = 10)) AS Articles
FROM
  `your-dataset.ga_sessions_test` AS t, UNNEST(t.hits) AS hits
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2016-09-27' AND '2016-10-24'
GROUP BY Author;
```

Comment: hum I can't make the second part `FROM
  "your-dataset.ga_sessions_test" AS t, UNNEST(t.hits) AS hits
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2016-09-27' AND '2016-10-24'` work.

Comment: Do you get a syntax error? Or something else? I don't have access to a similar table to be able to try it myself unfortunately.

Comment: `Syntax error: Expected "]" but got ":" at [10:45]`

Comment: Did you make sure to put backticks around your table name? I don't see that I used a `:` in the query above.

Comment: I've to find a way to call my table name with Standard SQL, isn't the same as legacy. Then I'll check your answer.

Comment: Ah I see. There is a [section on table names in the migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql#project-qualified_table_names) that might help, too.

Comment: new error `Cannot access field customDimensions on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [2:34]`

Comment: Do you mind sharing a job ID for the failure? That might make it a bit easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126938/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-elliott-brossard).

Comment: Ok it's working but I can't use it in google data studio need to be in legacy SQL. Will reopen a question ! thanks :)

Comment: Hi Elliott, I am trying to get the new visitor and user count by custom dimension value equals 1, can you please be advised of how to do it? I tried what you put in the answer, but it's not working. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a separate question.